# changing color of certain ranges in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe and I would like to plot a column in the data frame. expect that I want certain ranges along the column to be a different color in the plot. For ex: the plot should be black but from position 1:100 it should be a different color.

Ideally this will be a function I could just implement. The data frame looks like this, I want to plot column 4 and I would like to use plot in R to do this as well.

```
                  V1 V2   V3   V4        V5 newcol
1 ENSMUST00000000001  0 6692 3262 66.819600      0
2 ENSMUST00000000010  0   33 2574  0.065572      0
3 ENSMUST00000000028  0 3648 2143 39.598600      0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using base graphics. You just add a column that creates categories based on row number and then color the points by that category. In this case I've used color values (created with the `hcl` function) as the category names, but you can of course use whatever color function(s) or values you like.

```
dat = data.frame(y=rnorm(100))

dat$row.cut=cut(as.numeric(rownames(dat)), 
                breaks=c(0,25,50,75,100),
                labels=hcl(seq(15,275,length.out=4), 100,65))

plot(dat$y, pch=16, col=as.character(dat$row.cut))
```

[image]

You can also assign colors on the fly without creating a new variable in your data frame. For example:

```
plot(dat$y, pch=16, col=ifelse(rownames(dat) %in% c(26:50, 75:85), 
                               hcl(15,100,65), 
                               hcl(195,100,65)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above response. I found this to work pretty well.

```
 start = 0; end = 500; col = 'blue'
 plot(file$V4, type='l')
 clip(x1=start,x2=end,y1=0,y2=max(file$V4))
 lines(file$V4, col=col, type='l')
```